# Go exec external python script and get the returned output

Tags: python, go

In my Go file i use exec to run the external script:

```
cmd := exec.Command("test.py")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

The python script it's executed fine, but the go `fmt.Println(string(out))` prints nothing.

The question it's how i should return the value from the Python script to be read back again from Go?

Python pseudo code:

`def main():
    ...
    ...
    return value`

Comment: The python script should write to `stdout`. You could `print` or `sys.stdout.write`.

Comment: Show the code for test.py.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the bug, you need to put the full path to "test.py"

**Test**

I have two files in a directory:
    test.py
    test.go

The `test.py` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Hello from python")
```

and `test.go` is:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {

//cmd := exec.Command("test.py")
// I got an error because test.py was not in my PATH, which makes sense
// When i added './' the program worked because go knew where to find test.py
cmd := exec.Command("./test.py")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
$ go run ./test.go 
Hello from python
```